# Which type of overlay should be used for Java Game Development?

Tags: java, canvas, jframe, jpanel, 2d-games

I am trying to develop a game in Java.
It is a 2D game with not much logic in it.

I wondered if JFrame , JPanel or Canvas should be used for this?
Has one benefits over the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One popular approach is to override paintComponent in a JPanel like so:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    // put drawing code here
}
```

You can invoke this by calling `repaint` method elsewhere in the JPanel, usually in response to Key events for user-provided input, or from a `Timer` for fixed interval updates.

Here is some code you can use to get you started:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public GameFrame() {
        super("Game Frame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().add(new GamePanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new GameFrame();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });     
    }
}

class GamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Dimension PANEL_SIZE = new Dimension(640, 480);
    private static final int REFRESH_RATE = 1000;
    private static final int CHARACTER_WIDTH = 32;
    private static final int CHARACTER_HEIGHT = 64;

    private Timer timer = new Timer(REFRESH_RATE, this);
    private int currentRow = 0;
    private int currentCol = 0;
    private int randomRow = 0;
    private int randomCol = 0;

    public GamePanel() {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
        timer.start();      
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return PANEL_SIZE;
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawOval(randomCol, randomRow, CHARACTER_WIDTH, CHARACTER_HEIGHT);
        g.drawRect(currentCol, currentRow, CHARACTER_WIDTH, CHARACTER_HEIGHT);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int min = 0;
        int maxRow = (int)PANEL_SIZE.getHeight() - CHARACTER_HEIGHT;
        int maxCol =  (int)PANEL_SIZE.getWidth() - CHARACTER_WIDTH;

        Random rand = new Random();
        randomRow = rand.nextInt((maxRow - min) + 1) + min;
        randomCol = rand.nextInt((maxCol - min) + 1) + min;

        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();
        int rowIncrement = 0;
        int colIncrement = 0;

        if(code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            colIncrement--;
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            colIncrement++;
        }
        else if(code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
            rowIncrement--;
        }
        else {
            if(code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                rowIncrement++;
            }
        }

        if(isInBounds(rowIncrement, colIncrement)) {
            currentRow += rowIncrement;
            currentCol += colIncrement;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    private boolean isInBounds(int rowIncrement, int colIncrement) {
        int top = currentRow + rowIncrement;
        int left = currentCol + colIncrement;
        int right = left + CHARACTER_WIDTH;
        int bottom = top + CHARACTER_HEIGHT;

        return (top >= 0 && left >= 0 && right <= PANEL_SIZE.getWidth() && bottom <= PANEL_SIZE.getHeight());       
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/jackmead515/java_game_engine

The above link references my personal game engine. I use the java.awt.Canvas component and add it to a JFrame. It's useful to use the Canvas class as you can create a buffer strategy to preload your frames. You can do the same thing with JPanel, but you can only call a method called setDoubleBuffered(true) to activate double buffering (which should really be all you need. Depending on your game of course...)

NOTE: I apologize in advance. This game engine is currently in production, so if the links do not work, take it out on me! Additionally, if there is no Canvas in the future, it's because I found a better solution! Cheers!

https://github.com/jackmead515/java_game_engine/blob/master/src/main/java/com/engine/jsm/display/Display.java

^^^ Adding it to the JFrame.

```
GameCanvas canvas = new GameCanvas();
canvas.setBounds(0, 0, Stats.getScreenWidth(), Stats.getScreenHeight());
canvas.addMouseListener(InputManager.getMouse());
canvas.addMouseMotionListener(InputManager.getMouse());
canvas.addKeyListener(InputManager.getKeyboard());
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
this.add(gameCanvas);
this.pack();
canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
```

https://github.com/jackmead515/java_game_engine/blob/master/src/main/java/com/engine/jsm/display/GameCanvas.java

^^^ Call the paint method to invoke your stuff!

```
    public void paint() {
       BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
       Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
       g2.setFont(new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 12));

       Main.world.render(g2, this);

       bs.show();
       g2.dispose();
    }
```